# Reading customized tags/flags in outlook using ExchangeLib in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, exchangelib

I am reading the mails in outlook which contains customized tags/flags. Among which one is tag "Approved". I am trying to access the mail from particular sender whose tag is "Approved" using ExchangeLib Library in python.

I tried with multiple methods available in ExchangeLib library but no luck. I just wanted to print out this tag "Approved" in console. I tried with below methods:

```
ID_ELEMENT_CLS account add_field attach attachments body categories conversation_id culture datetime_created datetime_received datetime_sent deregister detach display_cc display_to effective_rights folder has_attachments headers importance in_reply_to is_associated is_draft is_from_me is_resend is_submitted is_unmodified item_class last_modified_name last_modified_time mime_content parent_folder_id register reminder_due_by reminder_is_set reminder_minutes_before_start remove_field response_objects sensitivity size subject supported_fields text_body unique_body validate_field web_client_edit_form_query_string web_client_read_form_query_string
```

Python - 3.7 Exchangelib - 3.3.2

[Image "Customized_Tags" contains "Approved" Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUn8x.png)

refer below Snap of code:

```py
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account

credentials = Credentials('john@example.com', 'topsecret')
account = Account('john@example.com', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)
for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
    #below is my requirement
    if item.tag == "Approved":
        print(item.tag, item.sender)
    else:
         pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flags are so-called extended properties in Exchange. There's information on working with extended properties in exchangelib at https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#extended-properties

You have to find the magic token that represents the extended property containing the flag data, and then define a custom field in exhcangelib and register it as a new field called `tag`.

Comment: Thanks for the details @Erik, We have gone through the link (https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#extended-properties)
and understood the procedure to set extended properties.

Tried to set as below:

`class Flag(ExtendedProperty):
    property_tag = 0x1090
    property_type = 'Integer'`

But couldn't find exact property tag/uuid for user defined "tag".

Comment: Hi Erik,

I also tried with below code but it still not giving tag value:

distinguished_property_set_id = 'PublicStrings'
property_name = 'test'
property_type = 'String'

Could you please help me finding the exact property tag.